# Spark 2.0 state: COMPLETE Exit status code -100 on yarn

Tags: apache-spark, emr

Can someone point me to documentation on what -100 exit code means? EMR cluster, spark 2.0.0 on YARN (per EMR standard spark-cluster deployment). I've seen https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_sg_yarn_container_exec_errors.html which gives some error codes, of which -100 is not one of them. Also, as a more general question, it seems that neither the YARN container logs and the Spark container logs contain much information on what causes such a failure ... from the YARN logs I see

`17/01/18 17:51:58 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 4164 executors.
17/01/18 17:51:58 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 4163 executor(s).
17/01/18 17:51:58 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 4163 executors.
17/01/18 17:51:58 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 4162 executor(s).
17/01/18 17:51:58 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 4162 executors.
17/01/18 17:51:59 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 4161 executor(s).
17/01/18 17:51:59 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 4160 executor(s).
17/01/18 17:51:59 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 2 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 4160 executors.
17/01/18 17:52:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 4159 executor(s).
17/01/18 17:52:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 4159 executors.
17/01/18 17:52:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Completed container container_1483555419510_0037_01_000114 on host: ip-172-20-221-152.us-west-2.compute.internal (state: COMPLETE, exit status: -100)
17/01/18 17:52:00 WARN YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed: container_1483555419510_0037_01_000114 on host: ip-172-20-221-152.us-west-2.compute.internal. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node
17/01/18 17:52:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Completed container container_1483555419510_0037_01_000107 on host: ip-172-20-221-152.us-west-2.compute.internal (state: COMPLETE, exit status: -100)
17/01/18 17:52:00 WARN YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed: container_1483555419510_0037_01_000107 on host: ip-172-20-221-152.us-west-2.compute.internal. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node
17/01/18 17:52:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Will request 2 executor containers, each with 7 cores and 22528 MB memory including 2048 MB overhead
17/01/18 17:52:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceled 0 container requests (locality no longer needed)
17/01/18 17:52:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Submitted container request (host: Any, capability: <memory:22528, vCores:7>)
17/01/18 17:52:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Submitted container request (host: Any, capability: <memory:22528, vCores:7>)
17/01/18 17:52:01 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 4158 executor(s).
17/01/18 17:52:01 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 4158 executors.
17/01/18 17:52:02 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 4157 executor(s).`

and Spark executor logs I see

`17/01/18 17:39:39 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/01/18 17:39:39 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/01/18 17:39:39 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called`

neither of which is very informative?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark on yarn mode end with "Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a \*lost\* node"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155421/spark-on-yarn-mode-end-with-exit-status-100-diagnostics-container-released)

Answer (score 0):

"Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node" tells you that the node has been lost.